# Cannot initialize the data source object of Linked Server in published apps using IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis

Trying to query a linked server with and without Openquery. The connections and queries work normally when executed from SSMS or when debugging any app in Visual Studio. Console apps that use the connection also work normally. However, once the web app is published the connection fails with an exception.

> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for >linked server "NetSuite".

I've tried rebooting both the app and SQL servers. Also deleting the app's folder and republishing and converting to an app in IIS didn't resolve.

The queries are really simple and working normally when using Management Studio or any non-IIS related app. Here is an example that is working there but not on published apps.

```
select * from openquery(NetSuite, 'select * from employees')
```

I've searched for hours and tried everything I can think of. Does anybody know why a linked server would stop working only in published .NET web apps using IIS specifically after an ODBC driver update? I would appreciate any help!

UPDATE:

For anybody who runs into this the solution ended up being really simple. When the app executes code it will be executing queries under the machine account of the IIS server. To resolve you have to give that machine account read/write permission to this folder:

> C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp

Thanks everyone for the suggestions!

Comment: a) Add to your question your connection string. b) Is there any reason why you are using OLEDB instead MS SQL Server specific providers?

Comment: OMG, as of **2007** MSDASQL [was being deprecated](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/selvar/2007/11/10/msdasql-oledb-provider-for-odbc-drivers/)

Comment: They're proprietary ODBC drivers provided by NetSuite. My connection string is using Integrated security. This all works fine in a console app, so that's the confusing part. I'm pretty sure it's IIS/web server related.

Comment: it's clearly a server issue... you need to debug it from the web server... as my answer clearly states. =)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out and report back. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your web app server is missing necessary drivers.  Try connecting from Web Server to your Linked Server via SSMS, you'll likely fail.

Check your application references, if you say it works on your desktop then copy ALL dll's (including the GAC referenced ones) to the \bin folder of your web app folder.

Comment: Check my comment in OP question, it is using a provider flagged as deprecated 12 years ago.

Comment: deprecated doesn't mean it would fail if appropriate drivers are present.  deprecated just means newer drivers won't support the call.